# Upgrade to MarkLogic 9.0-9.1 causing problems with optic queries through rest API

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-optic-api

We installed the Ops Director and had to upgrade from MarkLogic 9.0-5 to 9.0-9.1 and now we are having significant problems with our JavaScript optic queries through the Rest API.

Queries with joins that had previously been working returned errors that I was able fix by creating explicit view aliases within the query.  However, we still have a number of queries that no longer return results when serialized since the upgrade. These queries seem to contain parameters, although not all queries with parameters seem to be affected.  It may also have to do with the use of unions.

Has anyone had any incompatibility issues with upgrades that are similar to what we are seeing?

Comment: To clarify -- there is no version 9.1 (at this time). Are you referring to 9.0-9.1?

Comment: Yes, it is for 9.0-9.1.

Answer (score 0):

That's surprising.  Does the error log for the appserver show anything?

For investigating an upgrade issue, engaging with your MarkLogic support contact might be the appropriate path forward.

Comment: The error log only showed errors relating to the joins, which we were able to resolve. We have opened a ticket with MarkLogic to address a possible bug in the upgrade.